# Passing variable within erb loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I am new to Ruby and Rails. I am looping through a set of records and testing for age. If there is one record older than 14 days I want to set a flag that this set of records needs attention or is “bad”. I am struggling to figure out how to pass a variable into an erb loop, in this case I am using current_class.

In my controller I have this code:

```
def current_class
    @current_class = (params[:current_class]) 
end
```

In my application_helper I have the following code:

```
def name_class(t2 = nil, test_class)
    t1 = Time.now
    age = (t1 – t2) / 86400
    if test_class == nil || “good”
        current_class = age >= 14 ? “bad” : “good”
    else
    end
    return current_class
end
```

In my view I have the following code.

```
<% foo.each do |bar| %>
    <%= name_class bar.created_at, @current_class %>
    <%=h current_class %>
<% end %>
```

The output will be the evaluation of the current node but what I am trying to do is once I hit a record older than 2 weeks that current_class will have a value of “bad” for the rest of that set. Any pointers n what I am doing wrong?

Edited by request for clarity.

Generically what I am trying to do is persist a value through an erb loop.

So I have a set of 5 records named foo. Each record has an attribute named bar:

```
1 = A
2 = A
3 = B
4 = A
5 = A
```

When I loop through foo I want to persist the value of foo.bar in @baz. Once I encounter a value of B I want @baz to retain the value of B. Make sense?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One more thing. write `else
    end
    return current_class` as `else current_class
    end`

Comment: You have confused everyone more. What is `A` and `B`? Is it the value of `bar`? In your code you are not using `@baz` anywhere. All of sudden it appeared in the edited section.

Comment: @KirtiThorat OP wrote `if..else..end` block also wrong way.

Comment: OP - it **SHOULDN'T** be `current_class`, rather `@current_class`.

Comment: Neither current_class nor @current_class. It **SHOULD** be `test_class`.

Comment: @KirtiThorat I agree, I copied it wrong..sorry

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin `name_class` method is in ApplicationHelper. So, how would he access instance variable of controller?

Comment: @KirtiThorat Oh I see, It's in the ApplicationHelper. In that case you are right. Although this doesn't make much sense, `name_class` should be in a specific helper

Comment: @EricP Tell me if I've got this right. You want to set `@current_class` value to 'bad' when the `name_class` method finds one "bad record" ?

Comment: @EricP What if it finds multiple bad records? Shouldn't it keep the value of each one?

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin no, I am using this logic to change the presentation layer of an application. Once a single "bad" record is found then the presentation changes. A record set could have 10 "good" records, a single "bad" one triggers the change.

Comment: @RafaelRamosBravin I had the same question, what if there are multiple bad records. Good that you figured out what exactly the OP wanted. +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this in your view:

```
    <% @current_class = 'bad' if foo.any?{|bar| name_class(bar) == 'bad'} %>

    <% foo.each do |bar| %>
      <%= name_class(bar) %>
      <%h @current_class %>
    <% end %>
```

The first line of code will check if there's any bad records in `foo` and then set the `@current_class` to `'bad'` if there is.

---

And in your helper method:

```
    def name_class(bar)
      t2 = bar.created_at
      t1 = Time.now
      age = (t1 – t2) / 86400

      return age >= 14 ? “bad” : “good”
    end
```

The `name_class` method will just check if a single `bar` object is bad or good

Comment: This worked. Thank you! Would up vote it but I don't have enough rep yet :|

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to check each foo record if foo.created_at already past 2 weeks, then you'd want to 'tag' it as Bad, otherwise if still < 14 days, 'tag' as Good. If that's so and since you want it to persist, I would suggest that you add a column/attribute to the foo's table, say a Boolean named 'is_expired'. But my code below assumes that you won't be using a new column like 'is_expired'.

Personally, I would use 'scope' inside the model file of 'foo'. But if you just really want this in the view or you're going to still do some processing with it, I'll write something like below

```
<%
good_foos = []
bad_foos = []
%>
<% foo.each do |f| %>
    <!-- If GOOD FOO --!>
    <% if name_class(f.created_at, @current_class) == "good" %>
        <!-- ADD FOO'S ID TO 'GOOD' ARRAY -->
        <% good_foos << f.id %>
    <!-- ELSE IF BAD FOO -->
    <% else %>
        <!-- ADD FOO'S ID TO 'BAD' ARRAY -->
        <% bad_foos << f.id %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
<!-- PROCESS THE GOOD FOOS AND BAD FOOS HERE -->
<!--EX -->
<%= Foo.where(:id => good_foos).each do %>
    <!-- DO SOMETHING WITH FOO -->
<% end %>
```